# Xcode 4 ios simulator permissions issue

Tags: ios, xcode4, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to Lion and I have screwed up my ios simulator permissions...
You see, when I upgraded to lion I was forced to create a new user, and now all of the Xcode permissions point to that user.

I know this because I can load the ios simulator from that new user just fine, I cannot, however, do this form my original user account -- the simulator DOES open, but it immediately hangs.

I have tried recursively chowning both Xcode.app (which contains my iPhone Simulator.app) as well as the ios application support folder to set my normal account as owner
I also chmod'd those same two directories with both a+rwx and a=rwx in that order.

What other files does the ios simulator reference that need to have their permissions updated?

Comment: I am sorry to whomever downvoted my question. If you would care to explain why you downvoted me, perhaps I can update my question accordingly.

Comment: Please expend some effort to formulate a question instead of pasting an IRC chat log (with numerous spling erors). (EDIT: reverted downvote due to additional effort)

Comment: I figured that since I would basically be typing the same exact thing as what I typed into the irc log, it wouldn't matter. I have been fixing the typos as we speak. Sorry for the inconvenience, I will stop letting people know it was ever an IRC log

Comment: I would just try reinstalling Xcode as an Administrator user. (EDIT: the question is much more readable now, thank you)

Comment: Okey dokey, I applied a bit of clarity to my writing and removed any hint of IRC. Reinstall Xcode, eh? yikes :( I will try that. I can uninstall this latest xcode simply by deleting the app correct? or will I need to do some sort of uninstallation process? hmm letm e go google hwo to uninstall Xcode properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall Xcode. Here's how: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/

Comment: I have completely reinstalled xcode, and nothing has changed I am afraid :( Any ideas on what to do next? Let me see if the simulator somehow magically works on my other account......

Comment: Now this is very odd, I completely reinstalled xcode, but the permissions are still broken... Ugh

Comment: Sorry, no more bright ideas... :-) You could try the relevant Apple Developer Forums or the Xcode-users mailing list.

Comment: Managed to get this fixed by running a repair in OnyX, I'll accept your answer since it was the closest I got to one

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out OK. I guess repairing permissions is good for something after all...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to reinstall the Xcode. Xcode (at least the App Store version) is not owned by the user who installed it:

```
$ ls -ld /Applications/Xcode.app
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102  4 Oct 17:34 /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Also doing `chmod a+rwx` or `a=rwx` is certainly not a good idea. Not all files need to be executable (`x`) and what's worse **adding `rw` without thinking twice makes your system vulnerable**.

Comment: Alright, thankyou! For future reference, would a=rw- have been better? (- means that the value will not be changed if I understand the chmod man properly, right?)

Comment: Every file has its own unique permission - exactly what it needs. Unnecessary `r`, `w`, or `x` is a bad idea. And with `a` you're changing the permissions for **everybody**, which can be very dangerous. Also there's no difference between `=` and `+` in your case - it simply opens the file to read, write and execute for everybody, including 3rd party programs, etc.